# how does AWS S3 bucket Redundant storage works with filepicker/filestack

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, file-server

I am using Filestack https://www.filestack.com/ as fileserver and Amazon S3 as filestorage as complete storage solution for my clients. 
Filestack offers **CDN (Content Delivery Network)** which serves file from nearest **POP**. Also i have chosen Redundant Storage for my bucket on Amazon S3. Now my question here is even though my images are stored at Amazon S3 and filestack, every-time a file is requested from filestack with its URL for ex, https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/h3C4wbHoTSaSltX354Ui why am i being charged at Amazon for Data Transfer I/O? I need to understand working between the two.

Answer (score 1):

To set the cache-control headers for a filepicker.io URL you can add the following parameter: cache=true and it will set the headers to Cache-Control: max-age=315360000

For example: https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/h3C4wbHoTSaSltX354Ui?cache=true

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: that helped @Andrew .what about converted images? can it be saved in cache? so that everytime same conversion is not performed on the image?

Comment: as per the documents given by **filepicker** converted images are saved if we are using _CDN_ based links for 30 days. Is there a way to increase cache time for converted images?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "cache-control" header on your files in the S3 bucket?

If not, the CDN will probably contact S3 on every request.

Comment: can you provide any link regarding "cache-control" for S3 bucket?

Comment: Check out this answer on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501465/how-to-add-cache-control-in-aws-s3

Answer (score 0):

I just had a glance on Filestack, but not sure how it works. I guess S3 would be talking to your filestack using API.? In that case Amazon S3 has [bandwidth charges](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/), especially when it goes to Internet from AWS data center.

Comment: No i am not using any Amazon-S3 API, my images are uploaded on S3 via filepicker as it provides an interface to link your S3 bucket to filestack

Comment: Not sure whether this will work, but try giving requester pays bucket option in S3, so that you wont be charged.